# How to center cases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, cases

Consider the following system

```
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
S_0&=\{1,2,3,4\}\\
S_1&=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 \}\\
S_2&=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}\\
&\vdots
\end{cases}
\end{align}
```

which gives

[image]

How can I align the equal signs and `\vdots` such that I get something like this

[image]

Comment: you could use `\;\vdots` or some other space, but why `align` here? there is no alignment I would use `equation`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions, using the `\vdotswithin` command, from `mathtools`. The second solution requires `empheq` (which loads `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
S_0&=\{1,2,3,4\}\\
S_1&=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 \}\\
S_2&=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}\\
&\vdotswithin{=}
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

 or, with a shorter spacing:
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
S_0&=\{1,2,3,4\}\\
S_1&=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 \}\\
S_2&=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}\\
&\shortvdotswithin{=}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I think alignat works the same way. Perhaps the only problem would be centering the vertical dots at the equal symbol.